# How to effectively match a string with lots of regular expressions

Tags: php, mysql, regex, performance, algorithm

I want to be able to effectively match a string with a number of regular expressions to determine what this string represents.

```
^[0-9]{1}$         if string matches it is of type 1
^[a-x]{300}$       if string matches it is of type 2
...                ...
```

Iterating over a collection containing all of the regular expressions every time I want to match a string is way too heavy for me.

Is there any more effective way? Maybe I can compile these regexps into one big one? Maybe something that works like Google Suggestions, analysing letter after letter?

In my project, I am using PHP/MySQL, however I will be thankful for a clue in any language.

Edit:
Operation of matching a string will be very frequent and string values will vary.

Comment: There is a more effective way: precompute the "type" value whenever the string changes instead of trying to match every string to every possibility every time.

Comment: Did you perform some tests, why is it heavy?

Comment: Operation of matching a string will be very frequent and string values will vary.

Comment: Is it possible to provide all regex(or most of them) s which you are going to use. It may help to provide solution. Only if possible.

Comment: @amald These regexes are changing over time. I need a generic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, if possible, is grouping your regexes together and determine in which group a string belongs.

For instance, if a string doesn't match `\d`, you know there is no digit in it and you can skip all regexes that require one. So (for instance) instead of matching against +300 regexes, you can narrow that down to just 25.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is there any existing algorithm to calculate these groups automatically? Because these regexes are going to change over time.

Comment: @dev9 Not that I'm aware of. Taking the example, `\d`, if you have a regex that matches against `[3-5]`, it's not easy to determine automatically that it belongs in the `\d`-group.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up your regexes like this:

```
^([0-9])|([a-x]{300})$
```

Later, if you get more regex, you can do this:

```
^([0-9])|([a-x]{300})|([x-z]{1,5})|([ab]{2,})$...
```

Then use this code:

```
$input=...
preg_match_all('#^([0-9])|([a-x]{300})$#', $input, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    if (isset($val[1])) {
       // type 1
    } else if (isset($val[2])) {
       // type 2
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: But how is it more effective? it still validates every one of regexes just like a loop through them.

Comment: @dev9, nothing is going to be more "effective" that what you already have, since what you already have is 100% effective.

Comment: @dev9 As I understand your question, you don't want to iterate over a collection of regexes. By joining all regexes inside one only, the regex engine will iterate *optimally* inside the input.

Comment: @Alex Thank you, that's correct. But it is still too heavy and I am looking for something better.

Answer (score 0):

Since the regexes are going to be changing, I don't think you can *get* a generic answer - both your regex(es), and the way you handle them will need to evolve. For now, if you're looking to optimize the processing of your script, test for known strings before evaluating using something like `indedOf` to lighten the regex load.

For instance, if you have 4 strings:

- asdfsdfkjslkdujflkj2lkjsdlkf2lkja
- 100010010100111010100101001001011
- 101032021309420940389579873987113
- asdfkajhslkdjhflkjshdlfkjhalksjdf

Each belongs to a different "type" as you've described it, so you could do:

```
//type 1 only contains 0 or 1
//type 2 must have a "2"
//type 3 contains only letters

var arr = [
    "asdfsdfkjslkdujflkj2lkjsdlkf2lkja",
    "100010010100111010100101001001011",
    "101032021309420940389579873987113",
    "asdfkajhslkdjhflkjshdlfkjhalksjdf"
    ];

for (s in arr)
{
    if (arr[s].indexOf('2') > 0)
    {
        //type 2
    }
    else if (arr[s].indexOf('0') > 0)
    {
        if ((/^[01]+$/g).test(arr[s]))
            //type 1
        else
            //ignore
    }
    else if ((/^[a-z]+$/gi).test(arr[s]))
        //type 3
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/44MdX/